# Creating a View containing irregular sized rectangles (WebViews)

Tags: java, android, layout, view, responsive-design

I am trying to create an irregular and dynamic view on Android. It consists of many rectangles, which all could have different sizes. The view should be scrollable (displaying more content when you slide your finger up and down on the screen). Every rectangle is a WebView:
[image: layout]

**Question:** What would be the best approach to solve this problem, considering that it should be possible to create dynamic content? Dynamic content means, that data pushed from a server on the device is displayed without any user interaction.

I think with a ListView or a GridView, I can't create elements which are "merged" across ListView and GridView item borders.

**Bonuspoints:** Do you know of any algorithm which can calculate the layout parameters, such that the screen is filled with tiles, and no spaces are left empty?